# UV Layout Does Not Match Image Texture Files

Tags: texturing, uv

I have .fbx meshes exported from 3Ds Max. These meshes were originally extracted from Umodel (Unreal package file [.upk])

There are 3 separate texture files for this mesh 
[image]
but the UV layout is just 1 (it looks like all 3 UV layouts were placed side by side, combined to 1)
[image]

I was able to manually fix the issue by combining all three image textures following the mesh's UV layout 
[image]
[image]
but I'm wondering if there's an easy or automated way to do the following in Blender:

1. Separate the combined UV layout.
   That way, I can have 3 UV layouts for 3 image textures.

OR

2. Combine all 3 image files into 1 without having to manually do it using an image editor. Maybe a node or material setup.

Comment: You can adjust each part to match the textures, separate them by material, and then you can create a new UV map with a single texture to bake to.

Comment: Looks like the model was made using UDIM which enables having the uv sets tiled like that. Blender is supposed to get UDIM support eventually, but isn't able yet.